# Subir imagen a SQL Server - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sql-server, imagen

Gentes buenas acudo a ustedes busqué en muchos lugares no encontré cómo, quiero subir una imagen desde mi app a sql server, tengo entendido que debo covertirlo a string, mi app me permite sacar una foto o seleccionar una de galería, ahora solo estoy probando cuando la selecciono de galería hasta ahi todo bien me la muestra en un imagen view pero no se como puedo hacer para poder subirla a SQL Server

```
public class layout_admin extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView foto;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_admin);

    foto = findViewById(R.id.foto);

}

//Conexión a la DB
public Connection conexionBD(){
    Connection conexion=null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=prueba;user=sa;password=348;");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo conectar, verifique la conexión a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return conexion;
}
//On click de adjuntar imagen
public void adjuntar2 (View view){
    adjuntarimage();
}

//metodo de cargar image
private void adjuntarimage() {
    Intent intimg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intimg.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intimg.createChooser(intimg,"Seleccione aplicación"),10);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri path = data.getData();
        foto.setImageURI(path);;
    }
}
```

Entonces como lo puedo hacer? foto es mi imagen view hasta ahí me muestra la foto que yo selecciono pero debo poder mandarla a SQL cómo lo hago? como puedo convertilo a string?

desde ya agradezco mucho su ayuda. GRACIAS!

Comment: No guardes imágenes en una base de datos SQL, guardalas en una localización concreta y almacena la ruta u otro identificador para luego mostrarlas.

Comment: podrias guardar el base64 de la imgen pero esto provocara que tus apis que necesiten devolver esstos datos seaaan muy lentos, mejor subirlas a un directorio y guardarte la ruta en tu base

Answer (score 0):

Aunque este ejemplo es con Kotlin... creo que te va a servir.

Lo que hago es crear una función que devuelva byteArray (desde otros lenguajes como en C# es necesario hacerlo de esta manera) para poder subirlo a la base de datos. El tipo del campo en el SQL Server tiene que ser varbinary(max).

Función:

```
private fun imageToByteArray(): ByteArray{
    val drawable = imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable  //imageView sería el id que le das a tu ImageView
    val bitmap = drawable.bitmap
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    // El número '50' es el valor de la compresión que desea del bitmap. 
    // A menos valor menor calidad pero menos peso.
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream)  

    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

Después, dentro del setOnClickListener de mi botón, llamo al siguiente método:

```
private fun subirFoto(id: String, mat: String){
    try {
        val fotoArray = imageToByteArray()
        preferencias = getSharedPreferences(Preferencias.DATOSIP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
        // En mi caso saco la IP de un archivo 'preferences' pero se podría poner a mano
        val ip = preferencias.getString(Preferencias.IP, "").toString()
        val connSql = ConnSql()
        conn = connSql.conn(ip, "1433", "prueba", "usuario", "password")

        //consulta UPDATE por ID
        val query = "UPDATE tabla SET foto = ? WHERE id = ?"
        val stmtPrepare = conn.prepareStatement(query)
        stmtPrepare.setBytes(1, fotoArray)
        stmtPrepare.setString(2, id)
        stmtPrepare.executeUpdate()

        messageBox("Foto subida correctamente")
    }
    catch(e: Exception){
        Log.w("ErrorSubirFoto", "Error al hacer update en la base de datos SQL Server. \n\n $e")
    }
}
```